# How can I access a variable before I declare it?

Tags: python, scope

I am a total amateur when it comes to python and I have came across an issue:

```
if input() == existingUsername:
        print('Sorry, that username is taken, please try again:')
```

However, I need to access exisingUsername before it is declared, because I've defined it at the bottom of my code. I know you can do this in javascript with the let variable, but how can I do it in python?:

```
let existingUsername;
//code
existingUsername = 'name'
```

Comment: with `let existingUsername;` you are declaring it too; in python, you could use `existingUsername = None`

Comment: Python *doesn't have variable declarations*. If you try to use a variable that isn't defined, it will throw an error. Why would you want to do this anyway? Just *define the variables that you are going to use*

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable before declaring it.
You could however use an empty string:

```py
existingUsername = ""

# .
# .
# the rest of your program
# .
# .
username = input()
if username == existingUsername:
    print('Sorry, that username is taken, please try again:')
else:
    # assign new username here
    existingUsername = username
```

Comment: There must be a workaround, surely? How am I meant to have access to the variable at the beginning of my code when I am only able to declare it at the bottom? There must be a complicated way of doing a let variable :/

Comment: Why can you only define it at the bottom? What stops you from adding it somewhere above?

Comment: @SamuelHodge How is the interpreter supposed to let you compare a variable that does not yet have any value? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @CodingClown Because the user inputs the existingusername at the bottom of the if statements.

Comment: @SamuelHodge **then what value do you expect `existingusername` to have when it is being used**?

Comment: @khelwood The same way let does in js. Surely this is the most basic question I can't believe python doesn't have this.

Comment: So just add `existingUsername=""` before you need it. Then you can compare it. Or change its value if needed.

Comment: @SamuelHodge JS not Python. JS is filled with crap like this, and is one of the major faults people tend to find with it. On the other hand, Python *rarely* just works when you try to do something like use an undefined variable, instead, more sensibly, it throws an error. Just define a suitable value for the variable like in this answer. That is *the sane way to do it in JS as well*.

Comment: `let existingUsername;
if(<input> = existingUsername){
    console.log('This username is already taken')
}

existingUsername = 'define here'`

Is this following code not possible in python?

Comment: @SamuelHodge yes, it is, exactly as in this answer.

Comment: It more or less is by using my answer :) I changed my answer a bit to show you how. This should do exactly what you want it to

Comment: Another example, in JS when you have an object, say, and try to use an attribute that isn't defined, `obj.foo` then JS is happy to be like, "oh, there is no attribute named foo, so you *must* mean `undefined`!". Python is more like "oh, there is no attribute named foo, so *this must be an error*" and it raises an error.